# How do I create a timer in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a newbie in timer in WPF, and I need a code that every 5 minutes there is a message box will pop up. Can anyone help me for the simple code of timer?

That's what I tried so far:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); 
private void test() 
{ 
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick); 
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); 
    dispatcherTimer.Start(); 
} 
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // code goes here 
} 

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    test(); 
}
```

Answer (score 194, accepted):

In WPF, you use a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer).

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,5,0);
dispatcherTimer.Start();


private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // code goes here
}
```

Comment: Where it says "//code goes here", write " Messagebox.Show("message goes here"); "

Answer (score 42):

Adding to the above. Use the `DispatcherTimer` if you want the tick events marshalled back to the `UI` thread. Otherwise, use `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: +1 for explaining relevance to UI thread -- something that is critical to understand when working with WPF.