# Move mouse pointer

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to move the mouse cursor by means of C# code. Surprisingly there isn't any useful link or previously asked SO question about the same.

---

What I really want? Just some help to write a console app that runs in a `while (true) {...}` loop and moves the mouse every five or so minutes.

```
while (true) {
    MoveMouseToRandomPosition(); //Move mouse to multiple random positions
    Thread.Sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); //Go to sleep for the next five minutes
}
```

---

What I really really want? Be able to run this console app when I am working from home on a light day so that my status in outlook does not go Yellow (which means that I have been 'Away' for more than five minutes).

---

Guys, please do not take this as a 'Give me teh codez' question. Hints are perfectly fine. I can code the hints myself.

Comment: I am impressed by the honesty.

Comment: have you checked this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c

Comment: @Quakenxt: I didn't actually. It didn't show up in the recommended questions when I typed mine. Thanks.

Comment: @displayName I haven't found the recommended questions useful when asking a question.  You'll get better luck simply googling your question, and adding 'stackoverflow' on the end

Comment: I have used this: http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/ before

Comment: @Cyberdrew: I have used Caffeine for close to 2 years now. You may add it as an answer. :)

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869508/moving-mouse-to-stop-monitor-from-sleeping

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms you can do it using the Cursor object.

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

[Cursor.Position Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This one liner also works if you just need to set the cursor to a known coordinate. Also this code does not need to be inside of a Form like the answer code does: `Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);`