# How to use timer in VB.Net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dispatchertimer

I am trying to program a disco light machine in VB.Net.
I have four ellipses on a WPF, and I want them to "light up" (=change the fill from white to some color), then **wait** for 0.5s, then change the fill back to white - all according to a pre-written sequence.

I am trying to use DispatherTimer but I don't actually know how to make it work.
The ellipses are name pad0, pad1, etc...

```
Public Sub timer()
    Dim t As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
    AddHandler t.Tick, AddressOf dispatcherTimer_Tick
    t.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub dispatcherTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub play_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles play.Click
    Dim sequence = New Integer() {1, 0, 3, 2}
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        Select Case sequence(i)
            Case 0
                pad0.Fill = Brushes.Blue
                **this is where I want the timer to run!**
                padOff(pad0)
            Case 1
                pad1.Fill = Brushes.Yellow
                **this is where I want the timer to run!**
                padOff(pad1)
            Case 2
                pad2.Fill = Brushes.Green
                **this is where I want the timer to run!**
                padOff(pad2)
            Case 3
                pad3.Fill = Brushes.Red
                **this is where I want the timer to run!**
                padOff(pad3)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub padOff(ByVal pad As Shape)
    pad.Fill = Brushes.White
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an event driven world. No Paint, No Party

Comment: Just a note. There are a lot of predefined brushes in class `Brushes`, like e.g. `Brushes.White`. No need to create your own ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI only updates after *all* your code has executed. Thus, you don't see the change to Blue. Even worse, your UI completely freezes for 0.5s.

The correct way to do this would be to:

1. Set the color to Blue
2. [Set a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11559999/87698) to expire in 0.5s and set the color to White.

Other alternatives include:

- Start a new Thread that waits for 0.5s and then changes the color (be sure to use Dispatcher.Invoke here to change the color in the UI thread) or
- [start a BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5483565/87698) that waits for 0.5s and changes the color in RunWorkerCompleted (which is already executed in the UI thread) or,
- use an *asnyc* wait (e.g. `await Task.Delay(500)`), which causes the UI to be updated and responsive during the wait period.

Comment: This is WPF. Please don't use Timer and Control.Invoke. There is `DispatcherTimer` instead.

Comment: @Clemens: Point taken, I lowercased "timer". Note that the link behind it already links to a description of `DispatcherTimer`, which is the correct timer for WPF.

Comment: @Clemens: Ah, yes, it's Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks. I'm trying to use a Timer. I've updated my code, still don't really know how to make it work. Would be glad to get more help.