# How do I create a timer for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a `button_click` event and a `button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. I want to set a timer for my `button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. If the user's mouse is down for more than 1 second, then my code executes the `button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi.... well... basically, just as you say. It's exactly like that :-)

Comment: So if it is less than one second then it should do only button click?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a timer in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559999/how-do-i-create-a-timer-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a DispatcherTimer:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
...

DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += TimerTick;
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Start();
...

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Put some code here
}
```